# What is the difference between "to scry it and to scry on it?"

Tags: behind-the-scenes, inheritance-cycle, christopher-paolini

The acknowledgements at the end of *Eragon* have the following shoutout:

> Artie Bennett, the doyen of copy editing and the only man alive who understood **the difference between to scry it and to scry on it**.

What is "the difference between to scry it and to scry on it?"

Answer (score 8):

The obvious difference (to me, anyway) is:

- Arya scried Eragon, vs
- Arya scried on a small pool of water the battle under Farthen Dûr.

Scrying usually involves some surface on which the image of the object being scried appears. When you scry something, the image of that something appears. When you scry on something, the image appears on that something.

Of course, this seems to have been [intended to be humorous](https://www.paolini.net/2015/01/12/artie-bennett-copyediting-christopher/). Bennett says:

> The notion that copyediting is an often thankless task was belied—or
>   better, blown out of the water—by Christopher’s boundless generosity.
>   When he graciously acknowledged me in Eragon as “the only man alive
>   who understood the difference between ‘to scry it’ and ‘to scry on
>   it,’ I had to quickly learn the difference.